# How to enable daydream keyboard in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, daydream

How to enable daydream keyboard in unity 5.6 editor? The demo keyboard scene supplied with Google VR SDK v1.5 doesn't work in unity editor.

Answer (score 0):

In editor, the GVR keyboard does not display.  It reads from the physical keyboard to simulate input.